# C# Could not find file (any file) Windows 7 64bit

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64

```
string[] targetFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\d.txt");
```

I get  "Could not find file".

I'm sure there is a d.txt at the root of C, any suggestions?
i made a subdirectory called apples so c:\apples\d.txt i could still not read it.

this guy had the same exact problem 
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/system-io-file-exists-windows-7-a-t3915728p2.html

I've tried running as administrator.

Comment: Works for me.  Do you have rights to read d.txt? Do you need to elevate?

Comment: What are the results if you run your program with elevated permissions? It could (possibly) be a wonky ACL issue.

Comment: if you go to your project settings, are you compiling for x86, 64, or any CPU (il)?  Does it make a different to switch to any from x86?

Comment: forgive a dumb question, but how do you elevate permissions when using debug mode in VS2010?

Comment: is it possible you don't have permissions to access the file.
try run it as administrator.

Comment: @Mike.  You need to restart Visual Studio with permissions. From the Start menu - right-click Visual Studio and select Run As Administrator.

Comment: I ran as admistrator and still no, i also copy and pasted that exact file name into run and it opens fine

Comment: i have UAC set to "never notify"

Comment: OK - One more (because I've done it - and no, I'm not proud of it) - In Explorer, are you hiding extensions? Could the file's full name (really) be `d.txt.txt`? Look at the properties of the file.

Comment: Oh my freaking....i'm going to go hide now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to UAC and root access restriction for regular users. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206673/can-a-program-write-to-the-root-directory-of-a-disk-when-uac-is-turned-on-without/5206698#5206698).

From [UAC docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507861.aspx):

> Non-administrator users cannot create files on the system root drive,
>   for example, c:\

Answer (score 0):

Can you add it to subfolder.I suspect that C: drive has permission issue .

Or if you are running and EXE of that application run it with Admin privileges.